# Conditionally replace element value to 0. in blocks of small matrice

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix that can be split into some small blocks. I want to set the value of elements to 0. if their original value greater than 1.

I have implemented the replacements by :

```
a = RandomReal[1.5, {15, 15}];
b = Clip[a, {0., 1.}, {0., 0.}]
```

Now I want to further add the condition: **If one element is replaced by `0.` in a `3*3` block, all those `3*3 = 9` elements are going to be set to `0.` as well.**

For example, In my original matrix with dimension 15*15, it could be seperate into 25 small blocks with dimension`3*3`, if the below 3*3 block was one of them. I hope to set all elements to `0.` because there is a `0` on the last row. And doing the same operation to other small blocks if the condition satisfied.

```
{{0.460116, 0.870853, 0.206321},
{0.864099, 0.539186, 0.93472},
{0.78918, 0., 0.382635}}
```

Note: in the original matrix, there is no `0.` occurs, so when I see there is a `0` in `b`,I know it'd been replaced already.

I am having the feeling that maybe `SparseArray` could solve the problem, but it will generate unpacked arrays which I am trying to avoid. So I appreciate your thoughts about my problem.

Comment: `ArrayFlatten@BlockMap[If[Min[#] == 0, 0 #, #] &, b, {3, 3}]`?

Comment: No need to create `b`. `ArrayFlatten@BlockMap[If[Max[#]>1, 0 #, #] &, a, {3, 3}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be more elegant way.

```
 SeedRandom@2;
    a = RandomReal[1.1, {15, 15}];
    b = Clip[a, {0, 1}, {0, 0}];

    subset = Join @@ 
       Table[b[[i ;; i + 2, j ;; j + 2]], {i, 1, 15, 3}, {j, 1, 15, 3}];

    MatrixForm /@ 
     Table[If[MemberQ[Flatten@subset[[i]], 0.] == True, 
       subset[[i]] = 0 subset[[i]], subset[[i]]], {i, Length@subset}]
```

Or

```
MatrixForm /@ 
 Table[If[Min@subset[[i]] == 0, subset[[i]] = 0 subset[[i]], 
   subset[[i]]], {i, Length@subset}]
```

Or no need to create `b`.

```
subset = Join @@ 
           Table[a[[i ;; i + 2, j ;; j + 2]], {i, 1, 15, 3}, {j, 1, 15, 3}];

    ArrayFlatten@
 Partition[
  Table[If[Max@subset[[i]] > 1, subset[[i]] = 0 subset[[i]], 
    subset[[i]]], {i, Length@subset}], 5]
```

I suggest @kglr solution:

```
ArrayFlatten@BlockMap[If[Max[#]>1, 0 #, #] &, a, {3, 3}]
```